# Camera is not working on my Galaxy TAB

Tags: camera

Suddenly, the camera and flashlight are not working on my Galaxy TAB device. Android throws a camera/flashlight is being used by another app issue.
I have tried to uninstall the apps one by one and factory reset, but nothing has worked so far. I have run:

```
adb shell dumpsys media.camera > info.txt
```

which gives:

```
== Service global info: ==

Number of camera devices: 1
Number of normal camera devices: 1
    Device 0 maps to "0"
Active Camera Clients:
[]
Allowed user IDs: 0

== Camera service events log (most recent at top): ==
  06-03 19:35:35 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 18:58:49 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 18:58:46 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 18:58:33 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 18:58:28 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 16:00:27 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:59:16 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:47:29 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:45:36 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:35:20 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:25:20 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:22:41 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:22:41 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:20:52 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 15:20:52 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 13:51:54 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 13:51:51 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 13:37:58 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 13:15:15 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 13:03:03 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 12:22:11 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 12:18:29 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 12:09:06 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 12:09:06 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 12:08:51 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 12:08:51 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 12:08:50 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 12:08:50 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 11:41:59 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 11:36:09 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 08:40:54 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 05:38:45 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 03:44:35 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 03:08:13 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 02:33:07 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 01:50:41 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 01:50:38 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 00:38:16 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 00:35:47 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 00:25:47 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 00:15:46 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-03 00:05:46 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 23:55:46 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 23:45:46 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 23:45:45 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 23:41:11 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 23:40:21 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 23:40:01 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 23:18:07 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 23:18:07 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 22:53:26 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 22:24:28 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 21:52:09 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 21:52:09 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 21:52:08 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 21:52:08 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 21:51:19 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 21:04:52 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 21:01:03 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 20:54:12 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 20:38:47 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:13:15 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:13:13 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:04:24 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:04:24 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:04:05 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:04:04 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:00:32 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:00:32 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:00:31 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 18:00:31 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 17:38:48 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 17:38:20 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 17:38:18 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:27:07 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:26:49 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:26:49 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:26:22 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:26:21 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:26:21 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:26:21 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:23:31 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 12:23:31 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 11:55:45 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 11:48:33 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 11:43:24 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 11:33:24 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 11:23:56 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 11:23:56 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 11:23:55 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 11:23:55 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 09:07:18 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 03:20:11 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 00:31:11 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 00:21:41 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 00:11:41 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-02 00:01:41 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-01 23:51:41 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-01 23:51:15 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  06-01 23:49:53 : DISCONNECT device 0 client for package cameraserver (PID -1)
  ...

== Camera device 0 status 1 dynamic info: ==
  Device 0 is closed, no client instance
== Camera Provider HAL legacy/0 (v2.0, remote) static info: 1 devices: ==
== Camera HAL device device@1.0/legacy/0 (v1.0) static information: ==
  Resource cost: 100
  Conflicting devices:
    0
  API1 info:
    Has a flash unit: false
    Facing: Back
    Orientation: -1193648
  API2 not directly supported
== Camera HAL device device@1.0/legacy/0 (v1.0) dumpState: ==

== Vendor tags: ==

  Dumping vendor tag descriptors for vendor with id 3854507339 
  Dumping configured vendor tag descriptors: 32 entries
    0x80000000 (privatedata_reprocess) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.privatedata
    0x80010000 (cds_mode) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.CDS
    0x80010001 (cds_info) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.CDS
    0x80020000 (opaque_raw_strides) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.opaque_raw
    0x80020001 (opaque_raw_format) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.opaque_raw
    0x80030000 (count) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.crop
    0x80030001 (data) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.crop
    0x80030002 (roimap) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.crop
    0x80040000 (tuning_meta_data_blob) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.tuning_meta_data
    0x80050000 (enable) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.temporal_denoise
    0x80050001 (process_type) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.temporal_denoise
    0x80060000 (use_iso_exp_priority) with type 3 (int64) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.iso_exp_priority
    0x80060001 (select_priority) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.iso_exp_priority
    0x80070000 (use_saturation) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.saturation
    0x80080000 (exposure_metering_mode) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.exposure_metering
    0x80090000 (use_av_timer) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.av_timer
    0x800a0000 (dynamic_black_level_pattern) with type 2 (float) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.sensor_meta_data
    0x800a0001 (is_mono_only) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.sensor_meta_data
    0x800b0000 (enable) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.dualcam_link_meta_data
    0x800b0001 (is_main) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.dualcam_link_meta_data
    0x800b0002 (related_camera_id) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.dualcam_link_meta_data
    0x800c0000 (dualcam_calib_meta_data_blob) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.dualcam_calib_meta_data
    0x800d0000 (reprocess_flags) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.hal_private_data
    0x800d0001 (reprocess_data_blob) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.hal_private_data
    0x800e0000 (enable) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.jpeg_encode_crop
    0x800e0001 (rect) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.jpeg_encode_crop
    0x800e0002 (roi) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.jpeg_encode_crop
    0x800f0000 (strength) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.sharpness
    0x800f0001 (range) with type 1 (int32) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.sharpness
    0x80100000 (is_hdr_scene) with type 0 (byte) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.stats
    0x80100001 (is_hdr_scene_confidence) with type 2 (float) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.stats
    0x80110000 (brightness_val) with type 2 (float) defined in section org.codeaurora.qcamera3.brightness

== Camera error traces (0): ==
  No camera traces collected.
```

and

```
adb logcat
```

Where perhaps the interesting lines from the log are:

```
06-03 20:05:09.751  3488  3729 E SDHMS:SDHMS_UTIL_IO: e = /sys/class/input_booster/touchkey/time: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
06-03 20:05:10.123  1130  1824 W WindowManager: preserveSurfaceLocked: failed, no surface, w=Window{4a036a3 u0 com.sec.android.app.camera/com.sec.android.app.camera.Camera}
06-03 20:05:10.127   897   897 E mm-camera: <STATS_AEC ><ERROR> 2285: aec_biz_init: Motion Library loading error: dlopen failed: library "libMOTION.so" not found
06-03 20:05:10.183   667   667 E QCamera : <HAL><ERROR> cameraDeviceOpen: 586: Fail. Invalid camera capability info.
06-03 20:05:10.183   667   667 E SecCamDev@1.0-impl: Could not open camera 0: -19
06-03 20:05:10.183   908  3579 E CameraHardwareInterface: initialize: openSession failed! Function not implemented (-38)
06-03 20:05:10.192  2863  2900 W CameraBase: An error occurred while connecting to camera 0: Status(-8, EX_SERVICE_SPECIFIC): '10: connectHelper:1975: Failed to initialize camera "0": Function not implemented (-38)'
06-03 20:05:10.192  2863  2900 E SemCamera-JNI-Cpp: SemCamera_native_setup fail 10
06-03 20:05:10.192  2863  2900 E Request : openCamera failed - Camera device currently not available due to invalid operation
06-03 20:05:10.424  2977  2977 E dumpstate: can't find the pid
06-03 20:05:10.424  2977  2977 E dumpstate: Failed to find: /data/misc/anrd/
06-03 20:05:10.425  2977  2979 E dumpstate: *** command 'gzip -1 -f /data/log/core/..' failed: exit code 1
```

Unfortunately, I don't have enough android knowledge to understand the issue and the possible fix.
I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: I have found the one thing unreliable about Samsung devices, unfortunately, is their camera software.  Frequent "camera server" errors prevented me buying another Samsung device.